# Reveal Hidden Content When Using a While Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hidden

I am building a page which will have extra content revealed when the user clicks a button. That's fine I can do that with javascript or jQuery. Something like this.

```
<img id="doit" src="images/button_reddot.gif" width="125" height="22">
<script>
$( "img#doit" ).click(function() {
$( "#hiddenstuff" ).show( "slow" );
});
</script>
<table id="hiddenstuff" style="display:none" class="hotelform">
<tr class="hotelformborder">
<td>Extra content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My problem comes when I wrap that code in a PHP while loop to display versions of it multiple times. Regardless of which button I click, the hidden content is always revealed in the first rendering of the loop.

How do I make the hidden content show in the second rendering of the loop when I click the second button, etc?

**SOLUTION**

As Rory explained, the problem was the repeating use of ids. However using classes didn't quite work either as the hidden content was revealed in all renderings of the loop when just one button was clicked. This did set my brain running in a different direction though, so I set a $i variable and incremented it with each loop. Then the ids became

```
id="doit<?php echo $i ?>"
```

and

```
id="hiddenstuff<?php echo $i ?>"
```

Problem solved! Thanks to Rory and the others who contributed. StackOverflow is an amazing place.

Comment: Please show how you wrapped that code in a PHP while loop

Comment: The problem is when you use a loop you need to make sure the ID remain unique in the document. It is better to use class values in that case

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are using `id` attributes in your loop resulting in multiple ids, but they must be unique. Try using classes instead:

```
<img class="doit" src="images/button_reddot.gif" width="125" height="22" />
<table class="hiddenstuff" style="display:none" class="hotelform">
    <tr class="hotelformborder">
        <td>Extra content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can also then place your `<script />` in the `<head />` as one function can control all elements created within the loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('img.doit').click(function() {
            $(this).next('.hiddenstuff').show('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```